# ¿Como obtener los cambios actualizados de la base de datos desde Angular sin la necesidad de hacer el refresh en el navegador?

Tags: nodejs, angular, postgresql

Desde `Angular` tengo un archivo llamado `author.services.ts` donde obtengo una lista de autores.

```js
URL_API = 'http://localhost:4000/authors';

constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getAuthors() {
    return this.http.get<Author[]>(this.URL_API);
  }
```

Aca `books.component.ts` donde importo a `author.services.ts` para implementar el metodo `getAuthors()`

```js
authorList$: Observable<Author[]>;

constructor(public authorService: AuthorService){ }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.authorList$ = this.authorService.getAuthors();
  }
```

y aca `books.component.html` donde muestro los datos de la lista en un `<select>` del formulario.

```html
<div class="form-row">
         <div class="col-md-12 mb-3">
         <label for="validationDefault03">Autor</label>
          <select (change)="captureIdAutor($event)" class="custom-select" required>
          <option value="0">Seleccione un autor</option>
          <option *ngFor="let author of authorList$ | async" [value]="author.id_author">
              {{author.name}}
          </option>
      </select>                 
   </div>
</div>
```

Los datos los muestra perfectamente, el problema es que si yo hago un **insert** de un nuevo autor en la base de datos `postgreSQL`, los datos que estan dentro del`<select>` no se actualizan, al no ser que haga un refresh del navegador. Por eso mi idea es que al actualizar los datos desde la base de datos, automáticamente se reflejen en el `<select>`.
Tengo entendido que para lograr esto hay que utilizar el `Observable`, del modo que lo hice no da resultado.

Comment: Es que al hacer el insert debes devolver el objeto insertado y meter ese objeto en tu lista de autores. Eso o volver a solicitar todos los autores de nuevo para "refrescar" la lista sin refrescar la página

Comment: Gracias por responder,¿cómo debería  hacer para volver a solicitar todos los autores de nuevo ?

Comment: Pues...igual que los solicitas la primera vez

Comment: Porque yo desde Angular no tengo una funcion para hacer un insert de autores, porque directamente lo hago desde la base de datos.

Comment: Ah pues no. Entonces no puedes. Tu angular no tiene ni idea de si se han realizado cambios en la base de datos... De todas maneras, en una aplicación real no vas a insertar datos en la base de datos directamente, si no desde la aplicación. Si quieres hacerlo así, tendrás que estar constantemente comprobando los autores en la base de datos (pooling)

Comment: Perfecto, gracias!, creí que el Observable traía los cambios actualizados